# EF Core 3.1 throw System.InvalidOperationException when saving entity graph in Disconnected scenario

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

I have a disconnected scenario where I'm pulling data from a database, edit it and save it back.

I use two methods, one to get data and the other to save it.

Methods are as follows:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MasterObject>> GetDataAsync(int someId, CancellationToken ct)
{
    await using var context = new dbContext(_connectionString);
        
    return await context
             .MasterObject
             .Include(x => x.NavigationOne)
             .Include(x => x.NawigationTwo)
             .Include(x => x.NavigationThree)
             .ThenInclude(x => x.SubNavigation)
             .Where(x => x.NavigationOne.SomeId == someId)
             .AsNoTracking()
             .ToListAsync(ct)
             .ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public async Task SaveMasterObjectAsync(MasterObject masterObject)
{
    await using var context = new dbContext(_connectionString);
    context.DailyPlan.Update(masterObject);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Every time I call the `GetDataAsync` method and want to save one of the returned entries, I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException
> The instance of entity type 'SubNavigation' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'SubNavigation'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Comment: Add `AsNoTracking()` before `ToListAsync()`

Comment: It’s there, but still the  same problem

Comment: Maybe there other code that run and query the dbContext....

Comment: *Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.* - have you done this?

Comment: Yes, but this only gave me the id of the conflicted entity, but I struggle to find where it is being tracked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found where is the problem. In my ViewModel I have two lists, one contains all the entities and second is used to filter the first list and display to DataGrid via Binding. When I loaded entities directly to the second list, other words DataGrid is Bind directly to the list that holds the data, then I can perform Save method.

Another discovery is that when UI is running then problem occur. When I force to run method before UI is initialized everything works fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can clear tracked entities in **EF Core** before updating

```cs
public async Task SaveMasterObjectAsync(MasterObject masterObject)
{
    await using var context = new dbContext(_connectionString);
    var changedEntries = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added ||
                    e.State == EntityState.Modified ||
                    e.State == EntityState.Deleted)
        .ToList();

    foreach (var entry in changedEntries)
            entry.State = EntityState.Detached;

    context.DailyPlan.Update(masterObject);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: There are no tracked entities in a brand new DbContext